# Gurobi C++: adding variables with vector

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi, c++

I am solving an LP by using GUROBI - C++ combo.

Assume I have a variable $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I am adding this as a vector:

```
GRBEnv* env;
GRBModel* model;
vector<GRBVar> p;
```

Now I have $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ parameters, and I want to add a constraint $a^\top p\ \leq 0$, so I say:

```
GRBLinExpr sum_expo = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {// add all the coeffs given
                        sum_expo += a[i] * p[i];
}
model->addConstr(sum_expo <= 0);
```

Obviously, this is too inefficient. Is there a way that I can:

1. Define the whole $p$ vector as a multivariate GRBVar, rather than having a vector with all GRBVar values
2. Add a constraint $a^\top p \leq 0$ in a single line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I somehow taught using addVars in one command and then somehow giving inner-product defined constraint would be more efficient. So is what I am doing above standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [addTerms()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cpp_lex_addterms.html#cppmethod:GRBLinExpr::addTerms) to construct a linear expression in one call. According to the [documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cpp_lex.html) this is the most efficient way:

> - You should avoid using expr = expr + x in a loop. It will lead to runtimes that are quadratic in the number of terms in the expression.
> - Using expr += x (or expr -= x) is much more efficient than expr = expr + x. Building a large expression by looping over += statements is reasonably efficient, but it isn't the most efficient approach.
> - The most efficient way to build a large expression is to make a single call to addTerms.

Concerning adding multiple constraints in one call ([documentation about addConstrs](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/cpp_model_addconstrs.html)):

> We recommend that you build your model one constraint at a time (using addConstr), since it introduces no significant overhead and we find that it produces simpler code. Feel free to use these methods if you disagree, though.

Comment: thanks for this answer. How can I call that? Something like:```sum_expo::addTerms(a, p, p.size());```

Comment: ok fied by ```sum_expo.addTerms(&a[0], &p[0], X.size());```